# How to create an indexedDB gift bank using multiple keys?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, indexeddb

How to create an indexedDB gift bank using multiple keys?

I am trying to create a bank that contains a primary key with auto-increment and another key for future queries.

I'm trying to do this.

But it did not work out. When adding a record an error is shown.

```
db.createObjectStore("cidademaps", { autoIncrement: true, keyPath:['id', 'codeinfo'] });
```

Comment: An objectStore can only have one key. You can then add as many indexes as you need though. See [IDBObjectStore.createIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/createIndex)

Comment: Great. Thank you.